# Access object properties outside foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

I have a some data coming from the db via a model

```
public static function loadPermissions($user_role)
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table('role_has_perm');
    $builder->select('*');
    $builder->join('perms', 'perms.id_perm = role_has_perm.id_perm', 'left');
    $builder->join('roles', 'roles.id_role = role_has_perm.id_role');
    $builder->where('role_has_perm.id_role', $user_role);

    $query = $builder->get();

    return $query->getResultObject();
}
```

Now if I loop trough it with a foreach loop I can spit out the data.

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
    echo "id_role = " . $row->id_role . " " . "id_perm = " . $row->id_perm . " " . "role_name = " . $row->role_name;
    $role = $row->role_name;
}
```

However I don't always want to loop through the whole object. I want to access specific properties.
I want to access only the role_name for example.

```
$role = $query->role_name;
```

I get this error: Trying to get property 'role_name' of non-object

Am I handling the object wrong ?

Any input is welcomed :)

Alex

Comment: It looks to me like `$query` will be an array of objects, it doesn't really make sense to access `role_name` for the query as a whole, what would expect that to return? You could get the `role_name` for the first row by doing `$query[0]->role_name`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the $query variable contains an array. So you just need to access an element of the array by index. The following snippet would give you the first element of the array.

```
$role = $query[0]->role_name;
```

As an alternative you can [fetch a specific single raw](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows).